# Jinja How to get if checkbox is checked

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jinja2

I added checkboxes to an HTML table, and I would like to know if have any checkboxes checked. I have a script that works in Jquery that tells me the amount of checkboxes marked in a variable, but I haven't found how to use a Jquery variable in a Jinja if statement condition, or if there's any other way.

So what I would like to get is:

> **if any checkbox is checked or if Jquery var > 0 (I don't know which way is possible)**

```
{% if current_user.is_authenticated %}
    {% if var > 0 %}
        <form method="POST">
            <div class="form-group">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    {% else %}
        <div class="form-group">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="submiton()">Submit</button>
        </div>
    {% endif %}
{% else %}
    <div class="form-group">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="submitoff()">Submit</button>
    </div>
{% endif %}
```

JQuery function to get number of checkbox checked:

```
<script>
    function qtd_checkbox() {
        var numberOfChecked = $('input:checkbox:checked').length;
    }    
</script>
```

Comment: What exactly you need to do when `var > 0` hide an show htmls ?

Comment: @Swati if var > 0 it will receive the POST request method, otherwise I'll call another function.

Comment: then try using ajax .

Comment: @Swati great, thanks for the tips! Do you have any solution for this or have you ever encountered this type of problem?

Comment: see if that's related to backend then ajax would help but if you just need to hide/show form or the div then simply jquery will work . You can do same things if(var > 0) inside your jquery code and hide or show form depending on length  no need to put jquery code inside jinja .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find the solution I needed through Python instead of Jinja, so I had to check if I have any checkboxes checked using the `request` method.

So my solution was:
HTML:

```
...
{% for game in games.items %}
<tr>                
    <td name="ID_GAME" id="ID_GAME">{{ game.ID_GAME}}</td>
    <input type="hidden" name="ID_GAME" value="{{ game.ID_GAME }}" />
    <td name="NM_GAME"> {{ game.NM_GAME}} </td>
    <input type="hidden" name="NM_GAME" value="{{ game.NM_GAME }}" />
    <td name="NR_CRITICSCORE">{{ game.NR_CRITICSCORE}}</td>
    <td>
        <input type="checkbox" id="one_checkbox" name="one_checkbox">
    </td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Python:

```
...
if request.form.getlist('one_checkbox'):
    # Your code here
    print("success!")
```